# Where is the fogbugz connection string?

Tags: fogbugz

Where is the fogbugz connection string to the database?  Can I manually change this?

Answer (score 4):

#### 32-bit server or 64-bit

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Fog Creek Software\FogBugz\[your FogBugz install directory]\
```

#### 64-bit server with FogBugz running in 32-bit mode

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Wow6432Node\SOFTWARE\Fog Creek Software\FogBugz[your FogBugz install directory]\
```

Yes, you can change it manually, but you can also contact us for help on it.  customer-service@fogcreek.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. (if you have FogBugz admin priveleges that is...)

In the app, you can find it in Admin menu>Site>Database>Source